# Flex mobile app video playback error

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I'm playing a video (F4V). in debug mode, both desktop and device it runs smoothly, as soon as I export a release build the video plays but there is no sound, no amount of fiddling with codecs seems to fix it so I'm guessing that's not the problem. My thoughts are it has something to do with Air since the debug runs over it and the final release compile it as far as I can tell.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I had a similar issue using Flex, but not with AIR. The problem was that in debug mode everything was ok, but in release the app crushed. Sorry, do not remember what exactly was an error, and how I fixed, but I remember that there was something wrong in my code, like something had not finished initializing and was attemped to be called... But when in Debug mode, becouse of the app is running alittle slower, everything was initialized "just in time" and run ok.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? I remember video not playing with sound on some devices and video on others on pre-3.0 versions of Android back in AIR 3.3. Definitely possible it is still occurring (though I was using h.264 MP4 instead of F4V)